# explain tendermint deadlock in the docs

Tags: blockchain, tendermint

I read this in the tendermint docs :

> Note that it is not possible to send transactions to Tendermint during Commit >- if your app tries to send a /broadcast_tx to Tendermint during Commit, it >will deadlock.

Does that mean if my app sends another transaction while a previous one is in commit stage, the app will stop working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ABCI app logic processing the Commit message sends a `broadcast_tx_sync` or `broadcast_tx_commit` and waits for the response before proceeding, it will deadlock.

Executing those broadcast_tx calls involves acquiring a lock that is held during the Commit call, so it's not possible.

If you make the call to the broadcast_tx endpoints concurrently, that's no problem, it just can't be part of the sequential logic of the Commit message